# Cannot implicitly convert type Generic List to Class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to list courses and list semesters for every course.

**Here is my code**

```
public List<Course> GetAllCourses()
    {
        IList<App> app = App.GetAll();
        List<CInstance> ci = new List<CInstance>();

        for (int i = 0; i < app.Count; i++)
        {
            ci.Add(CInstance.GetInstance(app[i].Id));
        }

        return ci.Select(c => new Course
        {
            CourseId = c.Course.CourseId,
            Semester = ci.Select(s => new Semester
            {
               SemesterId  = c.Course.Semester.SemesterId
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
    }
```

I get Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collection.Generic.List<Test.Semester>` to `Test.Semester`

Can someone please correct this code for me?

**Update**

I'm exporting to JSON. So, it will be look like this

```
[
- {
   courseId: 123,
   courseName: "someCouse",
   semester:
   - {
      semesterId:26
   },
   - {
      semesterId:27
   }
}
]
```

Comment: How does the definition for the Semester-property look? Is it a list of Semester or a single instance? In the later case, change .ToList() to .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: To correct the code, we must first know your intention. Do you need a list of semesters or a single semester? The correction could be here or it could be in the definition of the property.

Comment: What is the `Semester` property of the `Course` class? Is it a `List<Semester>`?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Course` class to give a more clear picture?

Comment: I need list of Semesters for each course.

Comment: @HardCode You still haven't told us anything about `Semester` or your `Course` class.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the code but I would think that your `Semester` property is of type `Test.Semester` where it should be of type `List<Semester>` (or better `IList<Semester>`).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to do.  If it would only have a single semester, instead of

```
 Semester = ci.Select(s => new Semester
            {
               SemesterId  = c.Course.Semester.SemesterId
            }).ToList()
```

You could use FirstOrDefault()
like

```
 Semester = ci.FirstOrDefault(s => new Semester
            {
               SemesterId  = c.Course.Semester.SemesterId
            })
```

If it's possible that it's in more than 1 semester, you'll need to change your Semester type to be a list.

Comment: Then you need to change the type of your Semester property to be a list.  Right now the error you're getting is trying to set a List to a single instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a proper JSON-document with an array of `Semester` you'll have to edit the `Course`-class, so that the property `Semester` is a `List<Semester>` instead of `Semester`.

Example:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public List<Semester> Semester { get; set; }
}
```

If your `Course`-class looks like that, you should be able to run the rest of your function without any changes.